# Mathematical Writing, Indentation: Use Paragraph Indentation or Whitespace/Extra Line Breaks ("Blocking")

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

The majority of authors (that I've seen) use paragraph indentation in the standard way (with variation on the "first paragraph indentation" -- this question isn't about that, though). Some authors I've seen instead put an extra bit of whitespace between paragraphs (like SE does). (Two pictures are attached below.) In general, is the latter looked on favourably, or not?

Personally, I find it difficult to read. Particularly, if there is a display equation, then it's unclear whether the next line is a new paragraph or not. Sometimes it's not even clear if a proposition/lemma is ending. I feel paragraphs are helpful for showing that a new line of thought has started -- I mean, paragraphs in general have use, and so I feel removing this is not good! It's not a big deal, but having indents I find helps the readability.

The two pictures below give an example: it's not clear that "We now..." starts a new paragraph. (In this case, it may not be that important, but there are many cases where it may be.)

[image]
[image]

Is this commonplace for people to feel like this, or are most people not really bothered?

Comment: If you’re submitting it to a journal, don’t worry: they’ll make your formatting conform to their standard.

Comment: That is true, but I'd also like to put a copy on my own page. I'm aware that different journals have different conditions on exactly what you can put on your own page -- I'm not sure exactly, but some things like a final draft before publication, or something like that.

Comment: And anyway, even if the journal wants one form, I may want to put a different form on my own page. As such, I'm still interested in responses to this question :)

Comment: Your own page — that’s an entirely different issue. I like a small space between paragraphs, but if you notice, that’s not what happens in nonmathematical books, such as novels.

Comment: Thanks for your response. (Sorry for the delay in replying: was away!) I have noticed that indentation is overwhelmingly the case outside of maths (and, from my small sample, seems to be more in maths still). Don't you find it difficult not being able to tell when new paragraphs start? (after display equations)

Comment: Indentation is yet another issue. It looks as if for me it depends on whether I’m writing in LaTeX or html: standard LaTeX indentation, but no indents on my html pages.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "indentation is yet another issue"? I was asking about indentation vs small whitespace. (I've never seen a proper paper with no intent or whitespace... but I'm only about a year into my PhD so haven't seen that many!) \\ I understand where you're coming from with the html: it feels like html should be a little less formal, separating into chunks... (at least to me!)

Comment: Apologies, I guess I misunderstood which choice you were asking about. I was only thinking extra whitespace versus no extra whitespace. I do think of that as a totally separate issue from indentation.

Comment: Are you suggesting that starting a new paragraph by simply moving to the next line with neither a indentation nor whitespace is *ever* used? This makes it very difficult to tell when a paragraph ends even just with normal writing, never mind display equations, ssurely?

Comment: Just barely. I sometimes do it right here on MSE if the earlier paragraph is just a few words, and ends way before the end of the line. (My excuse is that the usual space between paragraphs is very high.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't completely understand. On MSE, if you press enter/return once, it doesn't start a new line, but pressing twice gives whitespace between the paragraphs?

Comment: To get no extra whitespace, you come to the end of the line with a period, give it one (or is it two?) spaces, then hit return. (If I recall correctly.)

Comment: Just tried: two spaces then return. But don't do that -- ever! =P

Comment: Maybe I actually tried it and changed my mind after looking at the result.